# Creating users in tenant using Microsoft Office 365 API and link it to chrome Id

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure

I manually created a user in Azure active directory for my project and I am able to get the users. I made a chrome extension and GCM provides me a ID which I want to be linked with the microsoft account.

So for each user, I want a GCM id (got this part) and an Azure AD Id linked together.

I was doing the following:

```
router.route('/users')
// create a user accessed at POST http://localhost:8080/api/users)
.post(function(req, res) {
  // Get an access token for the app.
  auth.getAccessToken().then(function (token) {
    console.log(token)
    var user = new User({
      officeId: token,
      name : req.body.name,
      email :req.body.email,
      chromeId : req.body.chromeId
    });
  user.save(function(err) {
      if (err)
          res.send(err);
      res.json({ message: 'User created!' });
  });
  });

});
```

However, what this does is take the auth token id, chromeId, name and email and just adds it to my mongoose database.

What can I do differently in order to get what I want to achieve? My teammate says what I am doing is correct but I checked the Azure AD and I don't see my user authorized there.

Btw, in the front-end, I ask a user to give their microsoft email and name.

Also, I merged my code with the code found here https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-Nodejs-Microsoft-Graph-App-only

```
 // @name getAccessToken
// @desc Makes a request for a token using client credentials.
auth.getAccessToken = function () {
  var deferred = Q.defer();

  // These are the parameters necessary for the OAuth 2.0 Client Credentials Grant Flow.
  // For more information, see Service to Service Calls Using Client Credentials (https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn645543.aspx).
  var requestParams = {
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
    'client_id': config.clientId,
    'client_secret': config.clientSecret,
    'resource': 'https://graph.microsoft.com'
  };

  // Make a request to the token issuing endpoint.
  request.post({url: config.tokenEndpoint, form: requestParams}, function (err, response, body) {
    var parsedBody = JSON.parse(body);

    if (err) {
      deferred.reject(err);
    } else if (parsedBody.error) {
      deferred.reject(parsedBody.error_description);
    } else {
      // If successful, return the access token.
      deferred.resolve(parsedBody.access_token);
    }
  });

  return deferred.promise;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create use in your AAD, you can leverage the Microsoft Graph API: [`Create User`](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_post_users), which is not implemented in your code or the `graph.js` code at github repository.

You need to implement the function yourself like:
[image]

Additionally, it seems that we have to [generate the access token](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/app_authorization) in Authorization Code Grant Flow to complete the operation. As in my test, I got the `Authorization_RequestDenied` error when I use the app-only flow access token to authorize the operation, and the graph server returned me the message:

> "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."

you can refer to https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-Nodejs-Microsoft-Graph-Connect/ for the sample.